# Is it possible to change few portions of the value in Augeas

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise, augeas

I would like to change the few portion in the value part of xml. Is it possible to do it in Augeas ?

**For eg:**

I would like to change the IP_ADDRESS alone in the following xml. It has been placed in three places. Is it possible to do it ?

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:IP_ADDRESS}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:IP_ADDRESS}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:IP_ADDRESS}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Augeas alone, that is not (currently) possible (but will probably be once we have native Lua support). For now, you'll need to use Augeas bindings and parse the value yourself.